# How to check if an application is present in /system/app folder?

Tags: android

I want to check if a specific apk is present in system app folder. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could just utilize the Java File API for that:

```
new File("/system/app/myFile.apk").exists();
```

Best wishes,
Tim